# How to upload own OS ISO on Microsoft Azure Cloud Platform?

Tags: azure

I want to install Custom Linux Distro like Mint/Backtrack/many more. I am unable to find any option that does it.

I am looking forward for Easy and Detailed guide on this matter. Assuming i don't know much about Hyper V or any type of virtualization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MSDN - Creating and Uploading a Virtual Hard Disk that Contains the Linux Operating System](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/)

Comment: Link is broken.